# How to store data into list with JavaScript?

Tags: development, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I want to store these information into my list called QuizList.

I have the following code:

```
var dtm = new Date();

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

var listItem = resultList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    listItem.set_item("Student", UserName);
    listItem.set_item("TestDate", dtm);
    listItem.set_item("Score", (score / testQuestions) * 100);
    listItem.set_item("QuizID", currentQuizItem.get_id());
    listItem.update();
    context.load(listItem);
 context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        $('#TestUI').fadeOut(500, function () { $('#TestReport').fadeIn(500, null)
```

How can I save these information into my QuizList? Any suggestion?

Comment: Start with the examples from Microsofts own documentation; you are missing half the code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me. If it's not working it should be because the variable "resultList" doesn't point to the list you want.

This line should be before the code you posted above:

```
var resultList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('QuizList');
```

Comment: this code works perfectly with this code i have the result goes into an report but i wanted to store these information into a list so this line of code you wrote need to be on top of function?

Comment: Yeah if you modify the code so resultList points to the QuizList as mentioned it should work immediately

Comment: how can I point ti QuizList please could you tell me

Comment: i modified the code but it is not working